# How to change a variable string inside another variable string from a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

```
var str1 = "Pedro";
var str2 = "Bye " + str1;

function changeStr() {
  str1 = "Dom";
}

console.log("Before", str2);
changeStr();
console.log("After", str2);
```

I want the above code to print "Bye Dom" instead of "Bye Pedro".
Also please attach the link from where I can get the conceptual knowledge for this.

Comment: `str2` is never changed? What makes you think it would be different?

Comment: `var str2 = "Bye " + str1;` stores the string "Bye Pedro" in `str2`. Changing `str1` afterwards doesn't change `str2`.

Comment: to change part of a string - you use the `replace` method - the conceptual knowledge for how you are doing it can be found in any javascript introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var str2 = "Bye " + str1;` will combine the two strings **at the point in time it runs**.

It doesn't create any kind of reference to the `str1` variable.

It will not update the value of `str2` if the value of `str1` later changes.

If you want to change the value of `str2` then you need to do so explicitly.

Generally, in this type of situation you would use a function instead of a string variable and every time you need the value call `str2()` to get the value computed from the latest value of `str1`.